# Dual Y-axis horizontal line position access in stratx plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to draw a horizontal line going through the 0.0 point over the plot produced by stratx's (https://github.com/parrt/stratx) plot_stratpd method.

How can I access the left Y-axis in this case, so that I can use `y=0.0`?

```
from stratx.partdep import *
X = df.drop('user_retained', axis=1)
y = df['user_retained']

plt.figure(figsize=(16,16), dpi= 80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
plot_stratpd(X, y, 'percentage_of_points', 'user_retained', yrange=(-0.3, 0.6), n_trials=10)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.axhline(y=134, alpha=1, linewidth = 2, linestyle = '-')

plt.show()
```

[image: The default plot produced by stratx, with the Y-value for the axhline found manually]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up an `Axes` and pass it to `plot_stratpd`. You can then use this Axes to plot the horizontal line at regular data coordinates:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,16), dpi= 80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
plot_stratpd(X, y, 'percentage_of_points', 'user_retained', yrange=(-0.3, 0.6), n_trials=10, ax=ax)
ax.axhline(y=0, alpha=1, linewidth = 2, linestyle = '-')
```

Example:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_diabetes
from stratx.partdep import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

diabetes = load_diabetes()
df = pd.DataFrame(diabetes.data, columns=diabetes.feature_names)
df['y'] = diabetes.target
X = df.drop('y', axis=1)
y = df['y']

fig,ax = plt.subplots()

plot_stratpd(X, y, 'bmi', 'y', n_trials=10, ax=ax)
ax.axhline(0)

plt.show()
```

[image]